# Unable to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk for Tomcat 8 via Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, aws-sdk, tomcat8, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I try to deploy my first app to elastic beanstalk via Eclipse. However, I encounter an issue: "The server does not support version 4.0 of the J2EE Web module specification." when trying to deploy to AWS Elastic BeanStalk Tomcat for 8 and 7. There is no issue if it is Tomcat 6. I checked and see that the project is web module 4.0.

Any suggestion to fix this problem???

[Error when trying to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk for Tomcat 7 or 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RS99W.png)

[Dynamic Web module version 4.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAZLX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's talking about the Java Servlet specification. Tomcat 9 was the first version to support Servlet 4.0, you've designated your project as requiring a server that supports Servlet 4.0, and now it's telling you that older versions like Tomcat 6 won't satisfy that requirement.

Change the facet version to 3.0.